# Guten Tag! The "Tag" pronunciation

Tags: accent

I wonder if its pronounciation is something like /'tæ:k/ or  /'taːk/ or something between them.

[Here](https://translate.google.com/?hl=fa#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=fa) in Google Translate the pronounciation of "Tag" is /tæk/ but amazingly [here](https://translate.google.com/?hl=fa#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=fa&text=tag) the pronounciation of "Tag" is /'te:k/!

Is there any difference?

how should we pronounce "a" in "Tag"?

Comment: Your first link seems wrong, I see no “Tag”.

Comment: Please remember to capitalize German nouns.

Answer (score 6):

/'taːk/ is the right pronounciation.
[Tag as a time](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tag_Zeit_Zeiteinheit)

/'tæ:k/ is an anglicism, which is the English word 'tag' taken into German
[Tag as anglicism](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tag_Schluss_Musik_Jazz)

Comment: What about /tɒːk/? Is this pronouciation possible? especially "Tag" in the phrase "Guten Tag"?

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi No, in Standard German it's definitely not /tɒːk/ (dialects may differ). It can be /tɑːk/, though, depending of the speaker.

Comment: there are some dialects where /tɒːk/ is used(mainly South East of Germany), but it would more likely be /dɒːɡ/ ...but in German it's definitly /'taːk/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Google Translate was confused by the English `tag`.

See https://www.dict.cc/?s=tag and https://www.dict.cc/?s=guten+tag for some real spoken examples.

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation is [taːk](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tag#Substantiv,_m), I have no clue what could have confused Google Translate.

Comment: What about /tɒːk/? Is this pronouciation possible? especially "Tag" in the phrase "Guten Tag"?

Comment: I guess the word *tag* like in *hashtag* could have confused Google.

Answer (score 1):

There is regional variation in the standard pronunciation. In Northern Germany, many people will pronounce this word as [ˈtʰax], whereas in the South, the pronunciation [ˈtʰaːɡ̊] may be more common. The prescriptivist standard pronunciation [ˈtʰaːkʰ] the others have mentioned is probably not much used in actual speech.

Comment: Hmmm... ISTM that the standard ponunciation is often used in standard speech, but perhaps not in the far North or South and certainly not in spoken dialect.